# Stopping time for Brownian motion

Tags: brownian-motion, stopping-times

Let $\{B_t : t \ge 0 \}$ be a standard Brownian Motion, and $T = \inf\{ n \ge 1 : B_{n} = n+1 \}$. Show that $P(T < \infty) < 1$.

I believe  $P(T < n) = P\{ B_n = n+1 \text{ for at least one } k < n \}$. However, we know that Brownian motion is normally distributed $(B_n \sim N(0,n))$ and therefore continuous. In this case, the measure of a singleton is zero which implies that $P(B_n = n+1) = 0 \; \forall n$.

Therefore, I'm confused about how I can calculate $P(T < n)$ if each event seems to have probability zero. I'm not sure if I missed something?

Comment: Is $n$ an integer valued variable , or real valued?

Comment: I believe integer valued.

Comment: Hi Doris, if you are talking about integer valued $n$, then note that $T<n$ depends only on the random variables $(B_1,B_2,...,B_n)$ which is a finite dimensional distribution of Brownian motion. It is well known that this is a multivariate normal distribution (in particular, a continuous one), so the probability of the set $\{B_1 = 2\} \cup \{B_2 = 3\} \cup \{B_3 = 4\} \cup ... \cup \{B_n =n+1\}$ is zero, because each such set is a hyperplane (so of Lebesgue measure zero). So even though $B_i$ are not independent (which is why the above argument of yours does not fully go through),...

Comment: their joint distribution is still continuous, and therefore $P(T<n) =0$ for all $n$. You can use the MCT now : this proves that $P(T < \infty) = 0$.